# Scheduled cloud function doesn't always work

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase as the backend for my project. and I want to run a cloud function at the same time every day. and what this function does is:

1 - get all the organizations

2 - for each organization get all the users in the organization

3 - for each user get their points and subtract from it(for example 10 pts)

4 - then create a data object and save it in 2 places.

here is my code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.setAbsetUsers = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 17 * * *') // mins - hours
  .timeZone('Africa/Cairo') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
  .onRun((context) => {
    const currentTime = Date.now()
    var theDate = new Date(currentTime);
    dateString = theDate.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Africa/Cairo' });
    split = dateString.split(" ");
    var datum = Date.parse(split[0] + ' 12:00:00 AM GMT+02:00');
    newTimestamp = datum / 1000;

    admin.firestore().collection("organization").get().then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((docOrg) => {
        /// enter in each org
        admin.firestore().collection("organization").doc(docOrg.id).collection("users").get()
          .then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {

              var collection_path = "test"
              var userPrivilege = String(doc.data().userPrivilege)

              if (userPrivilege === "USER") {
                collection_path = "user_attendance"
                // update user points
                var userPoints = doc.data().points
                var newPoints = userPoints - docOrg.data().lostPointsWhenAbsent
                admin.firestore().collection("organization")
                  .doc(docOrg.id)
                  .collection("users")
                  .doc(doc.id)
                  .update({ points: newPoints })
                  .catch(error => {
                    console.log('Error in updating writing document: ' + error);
                  });
                //End updating
              }
              else if (userPrivilege === "SUPERVISOR")
                collection_path = "supervisor_attendance"

              //enter user
              var data = {
                attend: "-",
                date: split[0],
                leave: "-",
                lostPoints: docOrg.data().lostPointsWhenAbsent,
                status: "absent",
                permission: "No",
                timeStamp: newTimestamp,
                uid: doc.data().uid,
                userEmail: doc.data().userEmail,
                userName: doc.data().userName,
                userTeam: doc.data().userTeam
              };

              admin.firestore()
                .collection("organization").doc(docOrg.id)
                .collection("attendance").doc(collection_path)
                .collection(String(newTimestamp)).doc(doc.id)
                .set(data)
                .catch(error => {
                  console.log('Error 1 writing document: ' + error);
                });

              admin.firestore()
                .collection("organization").doc(docOrg.id)
                .collection("users").doc(doc.id)
                .collection("attendance").doc(String(newTimestamp))
                .set(data)
                .catch(error => {
                  console.log('Error 2 writing document: ' + error);
                });
            });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Error 3 getting documents in ' + docOrg.id, err);
          });
      });
    })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error 4 getting documents', err);
      });
  });
```

sometimes it works as expected and other times it doesn't add all the data(for example it add only 10 users out of 20).

any solution?

Comment: Hi, you might want to add more information, so people will be better able to provide help if you provide information that can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem. Adding a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help a lot.